# How to make a triggered declarative pipeline stage in Jenkins to NOT build for tags

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a declarative Jenkins pipeline with some stages I want to run only for `tags`. This does work well with the [basic-branch-build-strategies-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/basic-branch-build-strategies-plugin/blob/master/docs/user.adoc) and the configuration within the multi-branch project that adds `Tags` within the `Build strategies`. Within the respective stage's section, I've added

```yaml
when {
  buildingTag()
  beforeAgent true
}
```

In addition, I have a test stage, that I trigger with a cron trigger to run over night. For that, I've added the trigger itself

```yaml
triggers {                
  // 1 am for tests
  cron('0 1 * * *')       
}
```

as well as the respective `when` section within the test stage:

```yaml
 stage('test') {                                                                                   
   when {                                                                                                  
     branch 'develop'                                                                                    
     expression { return currentBuild.rawBuild.getCause(hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger$TimerTriggerCause) }
   }                                                                                                       
   steps {
      ...
   }
 }
```

This works fine, except that a job is not only started for develop, but also for all tags within the repo. I then tried to add the following logic to the `when` section:

```yaml
when {                                                                                                  
  allOf{                                                                                                
    not {                                                                                               
      buildingTag()                                                                                     
    }                                                                                                   
    branch 'develop'                                                                                    
    expression { return currentBuild.rawBuild.getCause(hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger$TimerTriggerCause) }
  }
}
```

but without success. Any advice on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the definition of `buildingTag()`, or at least the return type?

Comment: Mh, in the [docs](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2018/04/09/whats-in-declarative/#new-when-conditions) they state: buildingTag - A simple condition that just checks if the Pipeline is running against a tag in SCM, rather than a branch or a specific commit reference.